# How to make the inner html show up below the form box

Tags: javascript

how would I make the .innerHTML show up on an element below the input form? Right now when I click an option and hit submit the url of the favorite stations pops up on the radio option itself.  This is for the second form. I want the inner html to show up below the form the inner html should show the url of the favorite station they selected from the second form. As of now it does show the url but the inner html does not show it below the form but instead inside the form. Please help ty.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 function radio() {
  var theMix = document.getElementById('mix');
  var theDrive = document.getElementById('drive');
  var theCountry = document.getElementById('country');
  if (document.getElementById("mix").checked) {
    document.querySelector("label[for=mix]").innerHTML = "https://wtmx.com/";

  } else if (document.getElementById("drive").checked) {

        document.querySelector("label[for=drive]").innerHTML = "https://wdrv.com/";

  } else if (document.getElementById("country").checked) {

        document.querySelector("label[for=country]").innerHTML = "https://us99.radio.com/";

  }

}
</script> 


<form>
  <p>List all the stations you listen to <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="A">The mix 101.9 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="B">The Drive 97.1 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="C">US 99 Country 99.5 <br>
  </p>

</form>



<form>
  <p>What is your favorite station?</p>
  <input type="radio" name="stations" id="mix" value="A">
  <label for="mix">The Mix 101.9</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="stations" id="drive" value="B">
  <label for="drive">The Drive 97.1</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="stations" id="country" value="C">
  <label for="country">US 99 Country 99.5 </label><br>
  <input type="button" value="Link To Favorite Station" onclick="radio()">
</form>
```

Comment: What is `<html !doctype>` supposed to be?

Comment: Because you're setting the `innerHTML` of an element inside the form - what did you expect?

Comment: Is that what you want ? `document.querySelector("label[for=country]").innerHTML = "<br>https://us99.radio.com/";`  ... can `<br>` helpfull for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<label for="country">

document.querySelector("label[for=country]").innerHTML = "https://us99.radio.com/";
```

That is the element you're trying to change with that code.  If you want that value somewhere else, create an element where you would like it.

```
    <div id="put_label_here">
</form>

document.getElementById("put_label_here").innerHTML = "Your Text";
```

Update:
To answer your question, I created a pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mopgbL

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking so I added two possibilities in here:

```
function updateLinkValue(e){
  document.getElementById("link").value = e.target.value;
  document.getElementById("anchor").innerHTML = '<a href="' + 
  e.target.value + '" target="_blank">' + e.target.value + '</a>';
}
```

That first bit updates the value of the button the second piece adds an anchor tag into the "anchor" span.  The anchor will work just as is there, the button requires some extra code:

```
document.getElementById("link").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(e.target.value != "Link To Favorite Station")
  window.open(e.target.value);
});
```

The variable "e" in both of these stands for event, which in our case, pulls the "click" event.  event.target pulls the element that was clicked.

Comment: how do i make it come up as a link though i did everything else u said but i was hoping to make it pop up as a link